# Спарсить строку в функцию sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Имеется файл, в котором есть строка с описанием функции, например `sqrt(x**2)`.

Нужно спарсить эту строку и сделать из нее функцию, чтобы можно было вычислять ее значения, подставляя `x`.

Я могу спарсить эту функцию с помощью `sympy`:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

function = "sqrt(x**4)"
parse_expr(function)
```

А как теперь ей пользоваться (то есть вызвать с определенным `x`) - не могу нагуглить. И еще вопрос - что будет, если переменных будет несколько, как тогда нужно будет объявлять функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Импортируйте `sympy`:

```
import sympy
```

Присвойте ваше выражение к переменной:

```
f = parse_expr(function)
```

Определите переменную `x` как символ:

```
x = sympy.Symbol("x")
```

Вычислите значение вашей «функции» (т.к. это не функция, а *выражение sympy*) применением метода `.subs()`, например

```
f.subs(x, -5)       // 25
```

или даже

```
f.subs(x, x+1)      // sqrt((x+1)**4)
```

Всё вместе:

```
import sympy
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

function = "sqrt(x**4)"
f = parse_expr(function)

x = sympy.Symbol("x")
print(f.subs(x, -5))          // 25
print(f.subs(x, x+1))         // sqrt((x+1)**4)
```